# Docblox: can not open input file docblox.php

Tags: php, documentation, docblox

Have just installed docblox on windows using PEAR.  Am running into the error 'can not open input file docblox.php'.  Any ideas?

docblox.bat and docblox.php both exist in c:\xampp\php, and this directory is in my path...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docblox.bat script uses the PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR environment variable to determine the location of your docblox.php.

Could it be that this has not been set on your computer?